# What does RADOM stand for in this datasheet?

Tags: radar

I found the following sentence in the datasheet of a FMCW module:

```
FMCW ramp is visible at the outputs caused by self-mixing effects, near objects and cover (RADOM).
```

My search results are flooded with information about the city Radom and the firearm. Is it something like a term for a collection of radar obstructing materials?

EDIT:

I see the suggestion RADOM standing for radome as both a comment and as answer. However, I wouldn't expect capitals if they mean radome. Is there any reference to these two being one and the same?

The context suggests RADOM being some kind of obstruction. As far as I know, radome polymers don't count as obstruction (that's why they're radome, invisible to radar).

Comment: Sounds like maybe it should be radome if it's talking about an antenna being covered, although maybe not because then it wouldn't be in caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it something like a term for a collection of radar obstructing
>   materials?

No, it's supposed to be an RF transparent cover for the antenna(s), and it's traditionally called a "RADOME".

Because it's not completely transparent it reflects a little non-Doppler shifted RF into the receiver, which causes the problem (akin to "ground clutter" for a pulsed RADAR) the data sheet was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to coverage of radars with specific materials, overall construction calls ["RADOME"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radome) - Radar Dome, mostly used for protection.

[image]
[image]